# El Capitan Safari Can't open localhost but 127.0.0.1 works

Tags: macos, network, safari

```
 127.0.0.1   localhost
 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
 ::1             localhost
```

This is my /etc/hosts configuration. I can use ip address 127.0.0.1 to open a loopback, but 'localhost' fails....
I have read these two posts:[El Capitan Safari Can't open localhost](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222787/el-capitan-safari-cant-open-localhost)
and 
[El Capitan Safari Can't open localhost](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222787/el-capitan-safari-cant-open-localhost), but none of the cases fits my problem.

The error message I got from Safari is

> Safari can’t open the page “‎localhost” because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection. This sometimes occurs when the server is busy. Wait for a few minutes, and then try again.

I also tried the localhost on Chrome, it gave me similar message...
Is there something wrong with setting alias?

Comment: If you try to connect to localhost with a browser, you should at least include in your answer which kind of server is running...

Answer (score 1):

After reading this post 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345132/127-0-0-1-is-working-but-localhost-not-working

I figured it out that I only need to comment out `::1  localhost`
then everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the theory behind why this would work , but for your IPv6 try

```
::1             127.0.0.1
```

instead

Comment: Please don't do that: etc-hosts file maps ip addresses to hostnames, eg. see [wikipedia - hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file))

Comment: @ThomasKettenbach - I know the theory, but that's how I persuaded mine to behave when IPv6 was introduced. I still don't have a connection that can use it, so it can stay semi-redundant until my ISP gets around to rolling it out.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue here. I'm running a local server and try to connect via curl, eg, the following **does not work:**

```
curl localhost 8080
```

but this:

```
curl 127.0.0.1 8080
```

works.

File: /etc/hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

My server only binds to ipv4, that's why i have to tell curl to use ipv4 stack:

```
curl -4 localhost:8080
```

works.