# Port Forwarding on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos

I've switched to macOS Sierra and am not able to get port forwarding working for localhost (http and https) using the loopback interface lo0. I'm using [pf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PF_%28firewall%29) and following the existing instructions for El Capitan but without success:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230331/81267, http://blog.brianjohn.com/forwarding-ports-in-os-x-el-capitan.html

Basically, I setup ifconfig:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 10.0.0.1 alias
```

Then I create a `pf` anchors file: `/etc/pf.anchors/myorganization`

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.0.1 port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.0.1 port = 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 7000
```

Add a reference to it in pf.conf (had to disable and then re-enable SIP to do this):

```
rdr-anchor "myorganization"
...
load anchor "myorganization" from "/etc/pf.anchors/myorganization"
```

I test the anchors:

```
sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/myorganization
```

and the result looks good:

```
...
TRANSLATION RULES:
nat-anchor "com.apple/*" all
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*" all
rdr-anchor "myorganization" all
...
```

I've enabled them:

```
sudo pfctl -evf /etc/pf.conf
```

I've added `localhost` to my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

But when I browse to `http://localhost` I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. If I browse to `http://localhost:3000` the site is working fine.

**Update**
I turned on pf logging and tried without the 10.0.0.1 alias:

```
rdr pass log (all) on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
rdr pass log (all) on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 7000
```

And the first time I hit http://localhost, I see the log:

```
00:00:00.000000 rule 4294967295/8(ip-option): pass in on en0: (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 59674, offset 0, flags [none], proto IGMP (2), length 32, options (RA))
    192.168.0.106 > 224.0.1.60: igmp v2 report 224.0.1.60
00:00:00.204784 rule 4294967295/8(ip-option): pass in on en0: (tos 0xc0, ttl 1, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IGMP (2), length 32, options (RA))
    192.168.0.3 > 224.0.0.252: igmp v2 report 224.0.0.252
00:00:00.093232 rule 4294967295/8(ip-option): pass out on en0: (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 11047, offset 0, flags [none], proto IGMP (2), length 32, options (RA))
    192.168.0.77 > 224.0.0.251: igmp v2 report 224.0.0.251
00:00:00.111608 rule 4294967295/8(ip-option): pass in on en0: (tos 0x0, ttl 1, id 60629, offset 0, flags [none], proto IGMP (2), length 32, options (RA))
    192.168.0.106 > 239.255.255.250: igmp v2 report 239.255.255.250
00:00:00.102426 rule 4294967295/8(ip-option): pass in on en0: (tos 0xc0, ttl 1, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IGMP (2), length 32, options (RA))
    192.168.0.3 > 224.0.0.251: igmp v2 report 224.0.0.251
00:00:00.000120 rule 4294967295/8(ip-option): pass in on en0: (tos 0xc0, ttl 1, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto IGMP (2), length 48, options (RA))
    192.168.0.3 > 224.0.0.22: igmp v3 report, 2 group record(s) [gaddr 224.0.0.251 is_ex, 0 source(s)] [gaddr 224.0.0.252 is_ex, 0 source(s)]
```

Subsequent hits to localhost add nothing to the logs and I see that the loopback interface lo0 doesn't show in that log, just en0 (Ethernet), so I'm not convinced this log output is relevant to the problem. I also tried adding en0 and en1 to the `/etc/pf.anchors/myorganization` file but same results.

Comment: Please add some details because as the question stands now it doesn't make much sense. Adding a second ip to lo0 doesn't necessarily resolve localhost to this ip. So what's the purpose of the 10.0.0.1 alias? Some docker thingy?

Comment: Essentially this question is asking how do the port forwarding. I'm looking for answers on how to do that

Comment: Entering 10.0.0.1:80/443 in the browser will redirect a request to 127.0.0.1:3000/7000! But I doubt you will get this working with localhost:80/443 since localhost is tied to 127.0.0.1 and **not** to 10.0.0.1.

Comment: What do you suggest I do to get localhost working?

Comment: RE: 10.0.0.1 - that line was something I found here http://serverfault.com/questions/102416/iptables-equivalent-for-mac-os-x#log-in and which I assumed was useful. I've tried the same without the 10.0.01 alias but with the same results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230331/93229) to the question: [What is the modern way to do port-forwarding on El Capitan? (forward port 80 to 8080)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/what-is-the-modern-way-to-do-port-forwarding-on-el-capitan-forward-port-80-to/230331#230331) is still valid.

You have several frictions/misconfigurations in your setup though:

- There is no need to establish an additional network address (i.e. 10.0.0.1) for lo0 if you don't have a second http/https host.
- A redirection:

  ```
  rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.0.1 port = 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
  ```

  will only redirect a request for 10.0.0.1:80 to 127.0.0.1:3000.

  A request for localhost:80 (which translates to 127.0.0.1:80 and **not** to 10.0.0.1:80) won't be redirected because there is no appropriate `rdr ...` line and you will get a connection error.
- Even adding the line `10.0.0.1    localhost` to /etc/hosts will not salvage your problem because *localhost* seems to be hard coded to 127.0.0.1.

---

To get your redirection working unload pf.conf with `sudo pfctl -d`. Then check your anchor and pf.conf:

```
rdr pass log (all) on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000
rdr pass log (all) on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 7000
```

and

```
...
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "myorganization"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
load anchor "myorganization" from "/etc/pf.anchors/myorganization"
```

Then parse/check *myorganization*  with `sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/myorganization` and load pf.conf with `sudo pfctl -evf /etc/pf.conf`.

In some rare cases you may have to [add](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/252468/93229) an additional line:

```
::1     127.0.0.1
```

to your /etc/hosts file. This doesn't seem logical though and may apply to older Sierra versions only. I haven't been able to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks, removing the 10.0.0.1 alias fixed the issue. (Not sure why initially doing that didn't work - see Update - there was likely something else wrong at that time. Adding the additional line to /etc/hosts wasn't necessary in my case.

Comment: In my case, I need to remove `::1. 127.0.0.1` to make the localhost destination work.