# Redirect Local Port through bridge to Internet Shared static IP

Tags: high-sierra, firewall, internet-sharing, pfctl

I have my cable modem (10.0.0.1) to my iMac (10.0.0.36), and my iMac (10.0.0.36) with a (bridge100 192.168.2.1) Internet Shared IP to my debian machine (192.168.2.34), and all of that is working perfectly. I would now like to forward port 80 from the internet through the bridge on my iMac to my debian machine...

```
10.0.0.1:80 <-> 10.0.0.36:8080 <-> 192.168.2.1:8080 <-> 192.168.2.34:80
```

I found the following [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100492/redirect-traffic-using-pf-along-with-internet-sharing), which lead me to

```
rdr on bridge100 inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.0.36 port = 8080 -> 192.168.2.34 port 80
```

However, it's not working... Now in the link they are going to localhost, and I found this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/709369/pf-mac-os-x-rule-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-a-specific-ip-port) which says i may need something like

```
pass out route-to (bridge100 192.168.2.1) from any to 10.0.0.36
```

But I have not been able to get `pfctl` to parse the above line correctly

Any ideas on how I can forward from 10.0.0.36:80 <-> 192.168.2.1 <-> 192.168.2.34:80 ?

Edit: The cable modem/router is a TG852G from Xfinity...

Edit: pfdump

```
                                        r     scrub-anchor "com.apple/*" all fragment reassemble
                                        r     anchor "com.apple/*" all
                                        r     anchor "usr.home/*" all
                                        n     nat-anchor "com.apple/*" all
                                        n     rdr-anchor "com.apple/*" all
                                        A       com.apple
                                        A       com.apple.internet-sharing
                                        A       usr.home
com.apple                               r     anchor "200.AirDrop/*" all
com.apple                               r     anchor "250.ApplicationFirewall/*" all
com.apple                               A       com.apple/200.AirDrop
com.apple                               A       com.apple/250.ApplicationFirewall
com.apple/200.AirDrop                   A       com.apple/200.AirDrop/Bonjour
com.apple/200.AirDrop/Bonjour           r     pass in on p2p0 inet6 proto udp from any to any port = 5353 keep state
com.apple/200.AirDrop/Bonjour           r     pass out on p2p0 proto tcp all flags any keep state
com.apple.internet-sharing              r     scrub-anchor "base_v4" all fragment reassemble
com.apple.internet-sharing              r     anchor "base_v4" all
com.apple.internet-sharing              n     nat-anchor "base_v4" all
com.apple.internet-sharing              n     rdr-anchor "base_v4" all
com.apple.internet-sharing              A       com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      r     scrub on en1 all no-df fragment reassemble
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      r     scrub on bridge100 all no-df max-mss 1460 fragment reassemble
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      r     scrub on bridge100 proto esp all no-df fragment reassemble
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      r     pass on en1 all flags any keep state
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      r     pass on en1 proto esp all no state
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      r     pass on bridge100 all flags any keep state rtable 7
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      n     nat on en1 inet from 192.168.2.0/24 to any -> (en1:0) extfilter ei
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      n     no nat on bridge100 inet from 192.168.2.1 to 192.168.2.0/24
com.apple.internet-sharing/base_v4      n     rdr on bridge100 inet proto tcp from 192.168.2.0/24 to any port = 21 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8021
usr.home                                r     anchor "SSH" all
usr.home                                A       usr.home/SSH
usr.home/SSH                            n     rdr on en1 inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.0.36 port = 8080 -> 192.168.2.34 port 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper command to redirect http traffic in your case is:

```
echo "rdr on $ext inet proto tcp from any to 10.0.0.36 port = 80 -> 192.168.2.34 port 80" | sudo pfctl -a com.apple/HTTP -f -
```

With $ext: the interface of the iMac connected to the router/modem (probably either en0 or en1). A redirect is done on the incoming interface and traffic! Therefore `rdr on bridge100 ...` doesn't make any sense here: you don't expect HTTP traffic with the destination 192.168.2.34 **from** the bridge100 **to** the network behind the very same bridge100.

The above command uses the temporary sub-anchor com.apple/HTTP and after a reboot it will be gone.

If you want to enable it permanently, create a separate anchor as outlined in this answer: [pfctl - howto add an anchor and make it active / load it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/312542/93229) or here: [Port Forwarding on Mac Pro with macOS Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297432/93229).

A `pass out route-to ...` is only required if you want to redirect outgoing traffic from the iMac.

---

In theory an additional static route is required on the (TG852G) router/modem:

```
route to 192.168.2.0/24 via 10.0.0.36
```

Here (different router though) it worked without it.

Double-NAT solutions are generally not recommended in SOHO environments and I suggest to attach the Debian Linux server directly to one of the Ethernet ports of the router/modem or an interconnected switch.

Comment: thank you for your reply, unfortunately, its still not working, any tips you can offer for troubleshooting?

Comment: @JeffreyL.Roberts Do you get an error message? Can you post a [pfdump](https://gist.github.com/vitaly/cd0024d232a3a134b00e5496e4e779b8) somewhere - either here (by adding it to your question as addendum) or at pastebin.com.

Comment: ill do as you suggest, and connect the box directly to the cable modem