# Apache localhost doesn't work: Safari can't connect to the server localhost

Tags: macos, safari, apache, mamp

I have upgraded to El Capitan a few months ago. I have followed a few guides to install and setup AMP: [Get Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin working on OSX 10.11 El Capitan](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/)

But I can't access my /Sites folder, because I can't connect to "localhost".

1. localhost (I actually tried with "localhost" typed in the address bar, and with my machine's address 192.etc) doesn't display "It works" message, instead I see this:

   ```
   Your website.

   Create and publish your own website quickly and easily using iWeb, Pages, and many other applications available for Mac OS X.
   ```

   and a few other sentences.
2. neither `localhost/~username`   (username = my name), nor `localhost/username` work - Safari displays a message that it can't connect to the localhost.
3. and of course I can't reach my Sites folder, because two previous steps don't work.

   ```
   httpd -v
   Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
   Server built:   Feb 20 2016 20:03:19
   ```

Apache configtest is successful:

```
apachectl configtest
Syntax OK
```

I have seen these discussions/pages:

- [El Capitan Safari Can't open localhost](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222787/el-capitan-safari-cant-open-localhost)
- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34060/discussion-between-fred-j-and-max-ried
- [Setting up a local web server on OS X](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083)
- [How to install MySQL on Mac OS X El Capitan](http://wpguru.co.uk/2015/11/how-to-install-mysql-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/)

but I am not sure if this is applicable to my situation.

Aslo, what's surprising, given the situation with apache, is that I can access phpmyadmin and mysql tables.

I will be grateful for your help!

Comment: I wasn't allowed to post other links I used due to lack of points, so I add them here https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3083
http://wpguru.co.uk/2015/11/how-to-install-mysql-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/
and others.

Comment: @klanomath, Thank you very much. Sorry, but how did you do that? I mean adding links, etc?

Comment: After gaining another 5 [reputation points](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) (now 6, then 11) your are allowed to add as many links as you want/need in your contribution. After gaining 2000 reputation points a user can freely edit anything without anyone else needed to review the edit. To add a link you can use the link symbol - the third symbot in the edit mode toolbar.

Comment: Apache is working.  The site you got is Apple's version of the generic "It's Working!" page.  What's happening is that [per user directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html) are not enabled and this must be done in `httpd.conf`

Comment: @Allan Thank you very much; I will read this to see what I have missed, though it seems I have uncommented all necessary items in httpd.conf - I have checked it numerous times. But I have to study the page you suggested.

Comment: @Allan unfortunately this tutorial was not helpful. (1) I have checked the Include part many time, and it is uncommented in httpd.conf;  (2) I checked again the information presented in tutorials I have mentioned; but I still can't access Sites folder and get the message: `The requested URL /~username/Sites was not found on this server`, though today I don't get the message zSafari can't load a page` when I try to load my `localhost/~username`.  It used to work though, a few months ago. I do need help on this issue. I am just learning, so the all is still difficult for me.